# How to run my trained Artificial Neural Network model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network

I have trained my ANN and saved it using Python. Now I want to use it can anybody help me.

It is a regression ANN, I have 7 independent variables and one dependent variable which is my output (Compression_Strength).

I have new data that I want to use my model to predict my Compression strength.
My independent variable is:

1. Cement_content
2. Water _content
3. Gravel _content
4. Admixture_content
5. Fibre _content
6. Fibre _length
7. Sand _content

The model should give an output of `Compression_Strength`

my Input that i want to predict [880, 900, 1200, 2, 1.5, 12, 600]

This is my code

```
df = pd.read_csv('...................csv', header=0)




model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", 
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-3), 
              metrics=['mae'])

x_train = np.asarray(x_train) y_train = np.asarray(y_train) x_valid =
np.asarray(x_valid) y_valid = np.asarray(y_valid)

model_history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000,
validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid)) '
```

Comment: Could you provide some details about your code / libraries ?

Comment: Show your code and a minimal example that can be used to run/understand the code.

Comment: Alright am updating my question with code

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using below code

```
New_prediction = model.predict(scaler.transform(np.array([[880, 900, 1200, 2, 1.5, 12, 600]])))
predict(New_prediction)
```